# Replicating Maven "dependencyManagement" tag from inside Gradle build

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to follow [this Spring Boot/Vaadin guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-vaadin) **however** I'm using Gradle, *not* Maven.

At the very top of that guide they say to use the following Maven XML:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.11</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

However I don't see a `dependencyManagement` task available via Gradle. So I ask: how do I replicate the same behavior as the `<dependencyManagement/>` XML element above over in "Gradle land"?

#### Update: current attempt

```
dependencyManagement {
     imports {
          mavenBom 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:10.0.11'
     }
}
```

Only problem with this is that when I add it to my `build.gradle` and then run `./gradlew clean` I get the following Gradle error:

> "*Could not find method dependencyManagement() for arguments...*"

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies, https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-bom-import

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet (+1) -- can you please see my updates? Is that along the lines you are thinking?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Thanks again, except Gradle now complains it can't find a method called `dependencyManagement()`...

Comment: That's because you haven't applied the dependency management plugin as explained in the gradle plugin documentation. Take the time to read this documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you a working build:

```
plugins {
    // the Gradle plugin which provides the “dependencyManagement” block
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.6.RELEASE'
    // add Java build functionality to be able to follow the Vaadin guide
    id 'java'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        // the Maven BOM which contains a coherent set of module versions
        // for Vaadin dependencies
        mavenBom 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:10.0.11'
    }
}

repositories {
    // find dependency modules on Maven Central
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // the dependency module you need according to the Vaadin with
    // Spring Boot guide; the version of the module is taken from the
    // imported BOM; transitive dependencies are automatically taken
    // care of by Gradle (just as with Maven)
    compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter'
}
```

Run `./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath` to see that all dependencies are available on your Java compile classpath now.

---

Edited to reply to the question in the comments: indeed, the import of the BOM leads to a slightly different set of dependencies than would be used without it. You can see the dependencies difference like so:

1. `./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath > with-BOM.txt`
2. Remove the `dependencyManagement` block and add a version to the single dependency: `compile 'com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:10.0.11'`
3. `./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath > without-BOM.txt`
4. `diff -u with-BOM.txt without-BOM.txt`

You can see slight differences like `org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents:webcomponentsjs:1.2.6` being used with the BOM and version `1.2.2` without it. The reason for that can be found in [the BOM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-bom/10.0.11/vaadin-bom-10.0.11.pom) where version `1.2.6` is defined and where the authors also mention the reason for that: “Transitive webjar dependencies, defined here for repeatable builds”

Comment: Awesome answer -- thanks @Chriki (+1) -- quick question for you: to confirm, it *sounds* like `com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter` wants to pull in certain dependencies, but by specifying `mavenBom 'com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:10.0.11'` we get to override what that start pulls in by default...am I understanding that correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. I’ve updated my answer with some more information on that.

Answer (score 5):

Generally maven `dependencyManagement` tag is used to import bom or control transitive versions.
Gradle does that with `platform` component, like below example.

```
dependencies {
  implementation platform('com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:10.0.11')
  implementation ('com.vaadin:vaadin-core')
}
```

This does not force you to depend on spring plugin for importing bom.