# How to add dependencyManagement in gradle like in maven?

Tags: maven, gradle

How to add the following Maven dependencyManagement in gradle?

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So far I do have the following, but where to add "type" and "scope"?

```
dependencyManagement {
  dependencies {
    dependency 'org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:11.0.2'
  }
}
```

Seems like this did the trick

```
dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom 'org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:11.0.2'
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with gradle myself. However, appearantly it is possible to run "gradle init" in the directory containing your pom.xml. This should migrate the maven configuration to gradle. Not sure how well it works for complex projects, but it should give you an overview on the language syntax at the very least. 

https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replicating Maven "dependencyManagement" tag from inside Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638350/replicating-maven-dependencymanagement-tag-from-inside-gradle-build)